# std::optional operator*() and operator->() - undefined behavior

Tags: c++

What was the motivation for having both operator*() and operator->() - undefined behavior when the instance is not initialized?

Why not treat it as an error and throw an exception?

Comment: performance/speed

Comment: [std::optional proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3672.html) quote : `Using the indirection operator for a disengaged object is an undefined behavior. This behavior offers maximum runtime performance.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Runtime performance.

See the [proposal, revision 4](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3672.html), which said:

> Using the indirection operator for a disengaged object is an undefined
>   behavior. This behavior offers maximum runtime performance.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that they are so low-level (it's just a memory access for the compiler) that Exception-Handling would be an overkill for this very performance-cheap methods.

Answer (score 1):

Performance basically. No check for an invalid value needed and no exceptions needed. If you want exceptions there's the `value` method.